# Convert array of JSON object to a js map

Tags: javascript, json

This is an additional question to [find a value inside array of JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29936971/3048967)

I get below Array of JSON objects from JSP

```
"Titles":[                          
    {
    "Book3" : "BULLETIN 3"
    }   
    ,
    {
    "Book1" : "BULLETIN 1"
    }
    ,
    {
    "Book2" : "BULLETIN 2"
    }    
]
```

On JS side, it is parsed and I see an array with 3 objects.

Now, I want to convert this array of objects into below JS map.

```
newTitles["Book3"] = "BULLETIN 3";
newTitles["Book1"] = "BULLETIN 1";
newTitles["Book2"] = "BULLETIN 2";
```

where `newTitles` is a js Object created via `new Object` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var newTitles = {};

Titles.forEach(function(obj){
  var key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
  newTitles[key] = obj[key];
});
```