# Javascript JSON Parsing using https url

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to fetch the json data using a url.Now i need to parse the Json data to fetch only feeds data from the url.I am adding the code below and the json  data.Can anyone help me how can i parse feeds data from the following json output.thankyou.

JSON DATA:

```
{
  "channel": {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "my_house",
    "description": "Netduino Plus connected to sensors around the house",
    "latitude": "40.44",
    "longitude": "-79.996",
    "field1": "Light",
    "field2": "Outside Temperature",
    "created_at": "2010-12-13T20:20:06-05:00",
    "updated_at": "2014-02-26T12:43:04-05:00",
    "last_entry_id": 6060625
  },
  "feeds": [{
    "created_at": "2014-02-26T12:42:49-05:00",
    "entry_id": 6060624,
    "field1": "188",
    "field2": "25.902335456475583"
  }, {
    "created_at": "2014-02-26T12:43:04-05:00",
    "entry_id": 6060625,
    "field1": "164",
    "field2": "25.222929936305732"
  }]
}
```

---

```
$.ajax({
  url: " https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/9/feeds.json?results=2",
  dataType: "json",
  cache: false,
  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    debugger;
    alert(xhr.statusText);
    alert(thrownError);
  },
  success: function(json1) {
    console.log(json1);
    if (json1.length == 0) {
      window.alert("The returned output array length is ZERO.");
    } else {
      var obj1, Feed;
      for (var x = 0; x < json1.length; x++) {
        obj1 = json1[x];
        console.log(obj1);
        if (obj1 == null || obj1 == "") {
          window.alert("\n The " + (x + 1) + "th object is NULL/BLANK.");
        } else {

          if (obj1.feeds == null || obj1.feeds.length == 0) {
            window.alert("\n The name portion of " + (x + 1) + "th object is NULL/BLANK.");
          } else {
            Feed = obj1.feeds;

            for (var k = 0; k < Feed.length; k++) {
              console.log("\n The deails of " + (x + 1) + "th Object are :  \nCreated_at: " + Feed[k].created_at + "\nEntry_id:" + Feed[k].entry_id + "\nField1:" + Feed[k].field1 + "\nField2:" + Feed[k].field2);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: First of all, this length has a typo in it: `if (obj1.feeds == null || obj1.feeds.lenght == 0) {`

Comment: Refer This Link.you will get some idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936971/find-a-value-inside-array-of-json-object

Comment: can you tell me the what that typo is i am unable to crack it@Marc-AntoineParent

Comment: @Anusha "length", not "lenght"

Comment: tq@phil.I have done it but i am not getting the feeds data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply parse the feeds array for individual feed :

```
json1.feeds.forEach(function(feed){
  console.log("th Object are :  \nCreated_at: " + feed.created_at
  + "\nEntry_id:" + feed.entry_id + "\nField1:" + feed.field1 + "\nField2:" + feed.field2);      
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/WSgdO6dZsyIAQVxWkTzr?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

`json1` isn't an array, it's an object. You need to access the `.feeds` property of the object to get to the array of feeds. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: " https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/9/feeds.json?results=2",
  dataType: "json",
  cache: false,
  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    debugger;
    alert(xhr.statusText);
    alert(thrownError);
  },
  success: function(json) {
    console.log(json);
    if (!json || json.feeds === undefined || json.feeds.length === 0) {
      window.alert("The returned output array length is ZERO.");
    } else {
      json.feeds.forEach(function (feed, index) {
        var indexPlusOne = index + 1;
        console.log("The deails of " + indexPlusOne + "th Object are :  \nCreated_at: " + feed.created_at + "\nEntry_id:" + feed.entry_id + "\nField1:" + feed.field1 + "\nField2:" + feed.field2);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

You could make it a little more readable if you use ES2015 and template strings:

```
$.ajax({
  url: " https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/9/feeds.json?results=2",
  dataType: "json",
  cache: false,
  error: (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) => {
    debugger;
    alert(xhr.statusText);
    alert(thrownError);
  },
  success: (json) => {
    console.log(json);
    if (!json || json.feeds === undefined || json.feeds.length === 0) {
      window.alert("The returned output array length is ZERO.");
    } else {
      json.feeds.forEach(function (feed, index) {
        var indexPlusOne = index + 1;
        console.log(`
The deails of ${indexPlusOne}th Object are:
Created_at: ${feed.created_at}
Entry_id: ${feed.entry_id}
Field1: ${feed.field1}
Field2: ${feed.field2}`);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Unless you really need to use the `cache` option I would also simplify it to just use `jQuery.getJSON` instead of `jQuery.ajax`:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/9/feeds.json?results=2")
  .fail((req, status, err) => {
    console.error(`AJAX call failed: ${err}`);
  })
  .done((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    if (!data || data.feeds === undefined || data.feeds.length === 0) {
      window.alert("The returned output array length is ZERO.");
    } else {
      data.feeds.forEach(function (feed, index) {
        var indexPlusOne = index + 1;
        console.log(`
The deails of ${indexPlusOne}th Object are:
Created_at: ${feed.created_at}
Entry_id: ${feed.entry_id}
Field1: ${feed.field1}
Field2: ${feed.field2}`);
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you try to work with string and try to get length (`json1.length`), but `jquery` under the hood return for you JSON object (because you've specified `dataType: "json"`).

So you have to work not with string but with object! And in your example you have simple object with property `feeds`, hence you need just traverse array which is in `json1.feeds`.

Here my example (I've just updated `success callback`):

```
json1.feeds.forEach(function(feed, i) {
  // This is your code, I've just copy-paster it here.
  console.log("\n The deails of " + i + "th Object are :  \nCreated_at: " + feed.created_at + "\nEntry_id:" + feed.entry_id + "\nField1:" + feed.field1 + "\nField2:" + feed.field2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer for the above issue is as follows.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: " https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/9/feeds.json?results=2",
   dataType: "json",
   cache: false,
   error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
   debugger;
   alert(xhr.statusText);
   alert(thrownError);
   },
   success: function(json1) {
   console.log(json1);
   json1.feeds.forEach(function(feed, i) {
  console.log("\n The deails of " + i + "th Object are :  \nCreated_at: " + feed.created_at + "\nEntry_id:" + feed.entry_id + "\nField1:" + feed.field1 + "\nField2:" + feed.field2);
});
```